# Start asp session OnClick (when click on a link)

Tags: javascript, session, asp-classic, onclick

I have this code:

`<a href="index.asp" onclick="<%Session("example") = True%>">LINK</a>`

The problem is that this result in the session example will be true when loading this page and not when clicking on the link.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the server code in the page runs on the server before the page is sent to the browser. What you end up with in the browser is just:

```
onclick=""
```

If you want to run server code when an event happens in the browser, you have to make another request to the server. You can either make a postback of the page and send some information back to the server (in querystring/formdata/cookie), or use AJAX to request a different page that contains the server code that you want to run.

---

#### Edit:

To use a querystring, make a reload of the same page and add for example `?ex=1` to the URL. In the server code you can check for this and set the session:

```
If Request.QueryString("ex") = "1" Then
  Session("example") = True
End If
```

Comment: Can you please make an example on how to do it - I don't understand it :)

Comment: Guffa - can you please give an example on how to do it then? :)